# Can Anyone Explain This Property of the Collatz Conjecture ($3n + 1$ problem)

Tags: trees, collatz-conjecture

I'm making a program that draws out a tree containing the first $n$ numbers, and how they all reduce to $1$. I noticed something interesting about the number of nodes that are required to connect numbers $1-n$ to $1$ that are not $1-n$. If you draw out a tree that contains numbers $1-n$, there will always be approximately $1.17 \cdot n$ numbers required that are not from $1-n$ to fill in the tree. In case that wasn't very clear, let me give an example. To place the numbers $1-10$ on a tree, you also need numbers $16,20,40,13,26,52,17,34,11,22,14,$ and $28$ to connect $1-10$ to $1$. That's $12$ other numbers, which is exactly $10 \cdot 1.2$. I know that's not the $1.17$ I promised, but that's because the sample size is quite small. Take a look at this spreadsheet: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Up-MIfQdqPFDRcF3CfqYBxSLigfe0ivEw5L33yfdl6Y/edit?usp=sharing) . You can see that for much larger trees, the average is very close to $1.17$. Can anyone explain this? Has this already been answered? I feel like this can't be just a coincidence.

Edit: If it could be proven that this quotient tends toward $1.17$ or some number near it as $n \to \infty$, then that means that there are no numbers that diverge, because then the quotient would approach $\infty$.

Edit 2: Tested it for a tree with numbers $1 - 1,000,000$ - still right around $1.17$

Edit 3: Tested all trees with numbers $1 - 1000, 1-1001,..., 1-10000$, and the average was $1.167687636032841$, with a standard deviation of $0.015784505982180175$

Final Edit: Tested all trees $1 - 10,000, 1 - 10,001,..., 1 - 100,000$. The average was $1.169015280407125$ and the standard deviation was $0.004822374427267592$

Comment: There was a recent seminar of Tao regarding Collatz conjecture and I seem to remember that he tries to estimate the maximum number reached starting from a number $n$. If you want to take a look at the video: https://www.matrix-inst.org.au/events/online-seminar-april-2020-professor-terry-tao-collatz-conjecture-2/

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You are considering the Collatz map $\operatorname{coll}(n)=\begin{cases} n/2&\text{if }n\text{ even}\\ 3n+1&\text{if }n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$ and the quantity $N(n)$ you are trying to estimate is $$N(n)=\left\lvert\left\{ \operatorname{coll}^k(x)\,:\, k\in\Bbb N\land 1\le x\le n\right\}\setminus\{1,\cdots, n\}\right\rvert$$ You are suggesting, in some sense, that $N(n)/n\approx 1.17$. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @Gae.S. From my very limited understanding of formal math syntax (sophomore in high school), I'm fairly certain that yes, that's what I mean. I'll have to do some reading to learn first and second order logic to become more fluent in math-lingo.

Comment: @Exodd I read recently that my boy Terry had made some progress, but I hadn't found any of his own talks online, so thank you for sharing that link.

Comment: @NoahK $\operatorname{coll}^k(x)$ stands for $\operatorname{coll}(\operatorname{coll}(\operatorname{coll}(\cdots\operatorname{coll}(x)\cdots)))$ where the map $\operatorname{coll}$ has been applied $k$ times to $x$. $N(n)$ is the cardinality of the set of numbers which are in the form $\operatorname{coll}^k(x)$ for some integer $k\ge0$ and some $1\le x\le n$, **and** which are not one of the integers $1,2,\cdots,n$ themselves.

Comment: @NoahK what happens if you take the maximum number generated minus n, instead of how many more numbers are generated? Does it change significantly from 1.17?

Comment: @Gae.S. Thank you for dumbing it down for me - yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @Exodd If you look up the sequence for $63$, the highest number that is reached is $9232$, which is quite a bit larger than $63$, so I think it's safe to say that my $1.17$ rule does not apply

Comment: Ive been downvoted and flagged so many times now, that im not able to ask any questions about the Collatz. That property makes sense because of the mixing properties of the numbers.

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy It definitely makes sense that the number would be in the 0.5 - 3 range intuitively but what I can't wrap my mind around is why the standard deviation is so ridiculously low.

Comment: I do not understand the argument that a proof that the limit exists would prove collatz. It makes sense that a diverging series can be ruled out this way, but how can we rule out other loops ?

Comment: Among the numbers greater than $n$, that you're counting, what proportion are even?

Comment: Your constant, 1.17, seems very close to $\frac76$, which feels somehow appropriate. From elementary considerations, I am able to account for $\frac56$, but I'm still scratching my head about the other $\frac13$.